# Why doesn't imagick work?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$im = new imagick('vui.pdf[0]');
$im->setImageFormat( "png" );
header( "Content-Type: image/jpeg" );
echo $im;
?>
```

I am using heliohost, but when i run this script, it show me a 500 Internal Server Error (http://iamsnoob.co.cc/open.php ), why?

Comment: Do you really have a file called "vui.pdf[0]"? Anything in the error logs?

Comment: Yes ofcause, because when i tried to renamed vui.pdf to other name, it tell me that it cann't open that file :D

Comment: The best thing would be to get hold of the error logs and look at the detailed error message

Comment: @decaze: I can give you my host detail, can you help me ?

Comment: Does that work with other image types? By the way, why are you opening a pdf, setting image type as png and outputting a jpg???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a wild guess, but ImageMagick requires Ghostscript to be able to open PDF files. It could be that Ghostscript is not present.

I would try with a JPEG image first. If that works with the same syntax, it's likely to be that.

The very best thing would be to look into the error logs and see what the 500 error is about exactly. Some providers offer access to the error log through their control panels or FTP logins.

**Edit**: A user has this to say in the [PHP manual on Imagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php#82366):

> To load image (usually vector image,
>   like PDF) with larger resolution than
>   image's default is, you have to set
>   resolution before reading the file,
>   like this:
>
> ```
> <?php $im = new Imagick(); 
> $im->setResolution( 300, 300 ); 
> $im->readImage( "test.pdf" ); ?>
> ```

this may well be the issue - try setting a lower resolution.

Comment: On many shared hosting platforms, memory is very limited and IMagick uses up a great deal on a large 300dpi PDF, running out of memory could well cause a 500 error.